# MS Access VBA: Reference Excel Application Object created in separate Module

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

This seems like it should be an easy one but I'm stuck.

I'm running a VBA script in Access that creates a 40+ page report in Excel.

I am creating an Excel Application Object using Early Binding:

`Public obj_xl As New Excel.Application`

Here is an example of how I am referencing the object:

```
With obj_xl
  .Workbooks.Add
  .Visible = True
  .Sheets.Add
  .blahblahblah
End With
```

The problem is that the procedure has become too large and I need to break the code up into separate modules.

If I try to reference the Excel Application Object from a different module than it was created in, it throws an error ("Ambiguous Name").

I'm sure I could do something with Win API but that seems like it would be overkill.

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: How are you referencing from another module? Please post a little code.

Comment: Hey Remou- I am refrencing it the same way I am in the example code above (using the With statement) but I am not declaring a new excel object. Let me know if that still isn't clear and I'll add some sample code. thx

Comment: After checking @SeanCheshire's answer, consider passing the excel sheet or workbook as an object to your next procedure.

Comment: @Remou - This sounds promising, unfortunately I have run so I can't test it right now. I will first thing in the morning and post back with the results.

Comment: Oh man I feel like a n00b! Remou - I just tested your suggestion at home and it works perfecty! I am passing the object, as you suggested, as an argument to the new subroutine - ie `Sub newRoutine(ByVal xlObject as Object)`. Thank you for the help on this! Much appreciated. If you want to post it as an answer, I will try to accept, assuming I can with my rep.

Answer (score 1):

this is the type of situation that can cause the error "Ambiguous Name"

```
Function Split(s As String) 
    MsgBox s 
End Function 
Function Split(s As String) 
    MsgBox s 
End Function
```

I know the example is trivial, but what you are looking for is a function , an object and/or a form control with the same names.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion...I was able to work around my issue by passing the object as an argument to the new sub. But if I run into the ambiguous name error again, I'll know to give the `Split` function a try. thx

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue, He's not suggesting that function specifically.  He's suggesting that you have 2 variables or functions with the same name.  In Sean's example, calling Split() would result in an error since the compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your declaration to **Global**, you can reference it in all your modules. For example, in one module, put this at the top:

```
Global obj_xl As Excel.Application
```

Then in an another module,

```
Sub xx()
     Set obj_xl = New Excel.Application
     Debug.Print obj_xl.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to be careful to capture all errors with a global variable, unhandled errors will clear them.

Comment: @PowerUser - thx for the feedback...On the first run this did not solve the issue but I will test again tomorrow morning to see if I can get it to work.